# 'telegram.error.TimedOut: Timed out' problem

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I ran into a problem with my telegram-bot program. when I launch it, after a couple seconds this error shows up. is it related to my internet connection ? or the code is wrong ?

the code:

```
from telegram.ext import *
def start_command(update, context):
    update.massage.reply_text("Hi. I'm a test bot")

def help_command(update, context):
    update.massage.reply_text("if you need help! search on Google")

def main():
    app = Application.builder().token('your token').build()
    
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_command))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))
   
    app.run_polling()
    app.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\request\_httpxrequest.py", line 200, in do_request
    raise TimedOut from err
telegram.error.TimedOut: Timed out
```

Comment: Please have a look at [this wiki page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Handling-network-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def main():
  app = Application.builder().token('your token').read_timeout(30).write_timeout(30).build()

  app.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_command))
  app.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))

  app.run_polling()
  app.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: I increased connection time besid read&write, by code below:

app = Application.builder().token(token).connect_timeout(30).build()

and i got :

telegram.error.NetworkError: httpx HTTPError: All connection attempts failed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).